# How to process JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Here is the JSON which is sent asynchronously to my php page. It is essentially a product list, which will be inserted into my mySQL database.

My issue is decoding the JSON in PHP. I can do this fine in js with the 'eval' function, but in PHP my efforts have resulted in a complicated series of explode and implode functions.

```
{
    "Product": [
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        },
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        },
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know php has a built in json_decode function, but in the PHP documentation they only show how to handle an array.

Any advice or help is really appreciated

Taylor

Comment: You can do this: [`$json_decoded->{'Product'}[0]->{'Product_Title'};`](http://codepad.org/g5Ogru5Z)

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Is `$json_decoded->{'Product'}` not equivalent to `$json_decoded->Product`? edit: yes http://codepad.org/fGzAZk7v although i still prefer associative arrays

Comment: @Mark - It is, that was just a relic of a previous attempt.

Comment: Converting database values to json data Watch these video... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvFXWqEqh6o

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you call `json_decode($data,true);`, your data will be:

```
Array(
    "Product"=>Array(
        Array(
            "Product_Title"=>"Cloth",
            "Product_Description"=>"Here is cloth",
            "Price"=>"100",
            "Category_ID"=>"1"
        ),
        Array(
.............
        )
    )
);
```

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to preserve the `stdClass` objects, you need to use the object-property syntax.

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "Product": [
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        },
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        },
        {
            "Product_Title": "Cloth",
            "Product_Description": "Here is cloth",
            "Price": "100",
            "Category_ID": "1"
        }
    ]
}
';

$json_decoded = json_decode($json);

// Note, it's usually a bad idea to use use count() like this;
// cache the count before the for() in a variable and use that.
// This is for demo purposes only. :)
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_decoded->{'Product'}); $i++) {
    echo "Products:
" . $json_decoded->{'Product'}[$i]->{'Product_Title'} . "
" . $json_decoded->{'Product'}[$i]->{'Product_Description'} . "
" . $json_decoded->{'Product'}[$i]->{'Price'} . "
" . $json_decoded->{'Product'}[$i]->{'Category_ID'} . "

";
}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Products:
Cloth
Here is cloth
100
1

Products:
Cloth
Here is cloth
100
1

Products:
Cloth
Here is cloth
100
1
```

http://codepad.org/JxYAO5De

Comment: Lol, can I just point out the irony in saying: `// Note, it's usually a bad idea to use use count() like this...` when actually doing it the right way would have been easier. I find myself doing this a lot in edits because people stupidly downvote based on shortcuts taken for simplicity, brevity, or demo purposes.

Comment: Or... it's an opportunity to show how not to do it *usually* and take the initiative to *say* don't do it this way. There are people who would see the *better* way (usually), and still fall back to the *easy* way.