# Printing JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file and I would like to print that object in JSON:

**JSON**

```
[{"text": "Aachen, Germany - Aachen/Merzbruck (AAH)"}, {"text": "Aachen, Germany - Railway (ZIU)"}, {"text": "Aalborg, Denmark - Aalborg (AAL)"}, {"text": "Aalesund, Norway - Vigra (AES)"}, {"text": "Aarhus, Denmark - Aarhus Airport (AAR)"}, {"text": "Aarhus Limo, Denmark - Aarhus Limo (ZBU)"}, {"text": "Aasiaat, Greenland - Aasiaat (JEG)"}, {"text": "Abadan, Iran - Abadan (ABD)"}]
```

I have tried with following method,

```
<?php   
  $jsonurl='http://website.com/international.json'; 
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);  
  $json_output = json_decode($json);        
  foreach ($json_output as $trend)  
  {         
   echo "{$trend->text}\n";     
  } 
?>
```

but it didn't work:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function var_dup() in /home/dddd.com/public_html/exp.php on line 5

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you `var_dump($json_output);` to see what you get? And to see whether json_decode makes an array out of your data?

Comment: "It does not work" is not a valid PHP error message though.

Comment: @quidage meant `var_dump($json_output)` - or alternatively simply `print_r($json_output)`

Comment: These links might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138625/how-to-process-json-in-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597941/how-to-echo-json-in-php

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function var_dup() in /home/dddd.com/public_html/exp.php on line 5

Comment: These links might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138625/how-to-process-json-in-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597941/how-to-echo-json-in-php

Comment: i meant `var_dump()` as i edited before

Comment: Your json decoding and loop is fine. That means there must be a problem retrieving the JSON with your `file_get_contents`. See this demo http://codepad.org/6vNqGVqz

Comment: Start with `var_dump($json)` to see what file_get_contents returns. Why are you setting `0,null,null` in the call? That won't do anything useful.

Comment: i have tried but this error is coming Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/website/public_html/exp.php on line 6

Comment: try to put a `exit();` or `return ;` before your `json_decode` call.

Comment: nothing is happend...@Yellow Bird

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php   

  $jsonurl='http://website.com/international.json'; 
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);  
  $json_output = json_decode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
  echo $json_output;
?>
```

by using [JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) u transform your json to pretty formatting, using json_decode($json, true) doesn't reformat your json to PRETTY formatted output, also you don't have to run loop over all keys to export same JSON object again, you could use those constants also which could clean up your json object before exporting it.

```
json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your comment, i will update my answer with more explanation :)

Comment: @Mortgy this doesn't work with json_decode directly, you need something like this: `json_encode(json_decode($json_ugly), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`    
 
taken from: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33226257/164374)

Answer (score 4):

use

`$json_output = json_decode($json, true);`

by default json_decode give OBJECT type but you are trying to access it as Array, so passing true will return an array.

Read documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php   
  $jsonurl='http://website.com/international.json'; 
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);  
  $json_output = json_decode($json, true);        
  foreach ($json_output as $trend){         
   echo $trend['text']."\n";     
  } 
?>
```

Thanks,
Dino

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/website/public_html/exp.php on line 6

Comment: There is a problem in your JSON which you download from that URL. Please double check if JSON is valid.

Comment: This codes works without problems:<?php
$json = '[{
 "text": "Aachen, Germany - Aachen/Merzbruck (AAH)"}, {
  "text": "Aachen, Germany - Railway (ZIU)"}, {
   "text": "Aalborg, Denmark - Aalborg (AAL)"}, {
    "text": "Aalesund, Norway - Vigra (AES)"}, {
     "text": "Aarhus, Denmark - Aarhus Airport (AAR)"}, {
      "text": "Aarhus Limo, Denmark - Aarhus Limo (ZBU)"}, {
       "text": "Aasiaat, Greenland - Aasiaat (JEG)"}, {
        "text": "Abadan, Iran - Abadan (ABD)"}]';

$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($json_output as $trend){
 echo $trend['text']."\n";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=[{"text": "Aachen, Germany - Aachen/Merzbruck (AAH)"}, {"text": "Aachen, Germany - Railway (ZIU)"}, {"text": "Aalborg, Denmark - Aalborg (AAL)"}, {"text": "Aalesund, Norway - Vigra (AES)"}, {"text": "Aarhus, Denmark - Aarhus Airport (AAR)"}, {"text": "Aarhus Limo, Denmark - Aarhus Limo (ZBU)"}, {"text": "Aasiaat, Greenland - Aasiaat (JEG)"}, {"text": "Abadan, Iran - Abadan (ABD)"}]
$obj = json_decode($data);
$text = $obj[0]->text;
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` in your json call eg :

```php
$obj = json_decode($data);
```

Instead write like this:

```php
$obj = json_decode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Hi Vishal. I've made a suggested edit to your answer to format the code. If possible could you also provide details as to what the fix is doing? Thanks!