# Decode json data from .json file in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to output some json data from a json file via php but it does not seem to work. I tried this:

```
<?php
    $jsonFile = file_get_contents('dataset/dataset.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonFile, true);

    echo $data->{'data'}[0]->{'letter'}
?>
```

The json file is following:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "letter":"A",
            "blocks":{
                "1":"0",
                "2":"0",
                "3":"0",
                "4":"0",
                "5":"0"
            }
        }
]}
```

Basically it should output the letter "A" but it outputs nothing. What did I do wrong?
Thanks

P.S. I tried to do it like here: [How to process JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138625/how-to-process-json-in-php) but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `json_decode($jsonFile, true)` your data is in array. So you should not access using object. Access data by array index. Try this..

```
echo $data['data'][0]['letter'];
```

[More about json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: This is true only because he used `true` as second parameter in `json_decode()` function, the use of second parameter make the function return as an `associative array`, I think you should elaborate your answer

Answer (score 1):

This says, you get an array (the true parameter):

```
$data = json_decode($jsonFile, true);
```

You can see this if you do this:

```
print_r($data);
```

Try this:

```
echo $data['data'][0]['letter'];
```